# Joomla display view not displaying site template

Tags: joomla

I am trying to load a view from my controller using the follow code but I only get a raw HTML view and does not show the site's template.

```
$view = $this->getView( 'download', 'html' );
$view->display();
```

Can some help me in what I am doing wrong to display the site's template.

I also tried a redirect but that did not work either

```
$this->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_atdwcsv&view=download'), false);
```

Edit: I figured out what was wrong with the redirect. Code I needed was

```
$this->setRedirect('index.php?option=com_atdwcsv&view=download');
$this->redirect();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't think you need to use the `display()` method on the view, I think you need to use `$this->display();` instead.

Comment: Still did not get it to work correctly but fixed my issue with the redirect so I now get the doenload view to display correctly via the redirect